# Should I format my new harddrive before installing linux?

Tags: linux

I am currently using windows on harddrive1, I just bought a new harddrive (harddrive2) and want to install a linux distribution on the new harddrive. Should I format harddrive2 on windows and then install linux? Or I can do that on the fly while installing?

Comment: it does not really matter.  Any data on the partition will be lost when the operating system performs a quick format of the partition automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty hard disk doesn't need to be "pre-prepared" using another OS as almost all OSes can format the new disk for you prior to installing the OS.